# Google maps API error handling

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing some test with the Google Maps Python API. The script is running fine, it loads GPS coordinates from a csv file and returns the address. It uses the googlemaps.reverse_geocode function.

However after a couple of "searches" I get an .....googlemaps.exceptions.TransportError: ('Connection aborted.....

It would be great if the script just continues when it receives an error.
I have no clue how to handle these error messages, the online documentation doesn't seem very clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that you're using the free API which [limits you to 10 requests per second](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits), and you'r Python interpreter probably works a little bit faster, I would use a queue and a timer to fire up to 10 API requests per second. That would be the correct way to do the job if this is indeed the problem you're facing.

A straightforward solution to your problem would be using `try` and `catch`, so when the `TransportError` exception raises you'll know that you should `time.sleep()` for a while and retry the last API request before moving on to the next iteration.

Comment: The sleep didn't work. Added a 1 second delay after 5 requests but still the same error. Maybe it is just a local network delay.
The try command worked excellent, wasn't aware of this function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just so you know, this approach is far from best practice. I would suggest you drill down for the reason that the exception raises and solve it, or handle it in a way that will not make it raise. If you just want to get a job done, well that's, as I wrote earlier, a straightforward solution - far from best practice.